# I would like annotations to cleanly fall into the center of the shape drawn. Unknown cause of annotation offset

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, mkmapview

All,

I've recently followed this tutorial on drawing smooth line's using cocos2d. http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/

It's a great tutorial. I got it working with a layer over a `MapViewController`. The user can "single tap" the screen to hide the search bar and drawn on the map. The idea is that a user will draw a circle or a shape such as a square (let's just saw it'll be a circle), and an annotation will appear in the center of the shape drawn.

At the moment, **I have annotations appearing at this "center" when the user single taps again to re-summon the search bar and cancel drawing mode**. However, *the center of the points collected always has an undesirable offset--it seems to be sporadic, sometimes the pins fall near the center of the shape drawn and other times they appear on the other side of the iPhone screen.*

I've collected the `topLeft`, `bottomLeft`, `topRight`, `bottomRight` points of a shape drawn--then I get the center point given that rect. I take into account the origin of the rect as well.

Once I have the center point from the `CGRect` derived from the drawn points, I use iOS's default method to convert the screen touch-point to a location on the map.

However, there is a seemingly random offset. I've been thinking on this problem all day, and I can't seem to find a solution.

I would like annotations to cleanly fall into the center of the shape drawn. Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated. The project and [entire source code can be found here](https://github.com/Glchriste/Todo-).

```
- (void) setMarker {
    CGPoint point = [[MapSingleton mapSingleton] getMarkerPoint];
    NSLog(@"%f,%f", point.x, point.y);

    if(point.x >= 0 && point.y >= 0) {
        //Place marker annotation
        Annotation *annotation = [[Annotation alloc] init];
        annotation.coordinate = [self convertScreenToLatLong:point];
        annotation.color = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        annotation.title = @"New Annotation";

        // Add to map
        [self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
    }
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D)convertScreenToLatLong:(CGPoint)point {
    CGPoint tapPoint = point; // the tap point on the MKMapView on the device
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates = [mapView convertPoint:tapPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView]; // _customMapView in an MKMapView instance
    NSLog(@"Tap at : %f, %f", coordinates.latitude, coordinates.longitude);
    return coordinates;
}
```

I want **[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mb9cg.png)**, **[not this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFC7l.png)**.

Comment: You probably want to add the code where you are calculating the center of the drawn area. It sounds to me like that is where your problem is. It looks like it is in -(CGPoint)getMarkerPoint;

Comment: Can you be more specific? I calculate the center in lineDrawer.m's getCenterPoint method. The class is on the Github link I posted above. I can add more source code to my post.

Comment: It is preferable to post all relevant code into the S.O. post as external links have a habit of going stale or changing. Once that code is here I suspect you will get an answer a lot faster.